# Removing folder name with special characters

Tags: bash

I would like to know how can I remove/access this folder?

```
$ ls -l
total 1
drwxrwxr-x 3 vsc44581 vsc44581 4096 Sep  8 10:19 ''$'\033'
$ rm -rf \'\'*
$ ls
''$'\033'
$ rm -rf \'\'\$*
$ ls
''$'\033'
$ ls \'\'*
ls: cannot access ''\'''\''*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can try `printf '%q\n' *`  and that will return `$'\E'`   so.  `rm $'\E'` or `cd $'\E'` will  work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some modern versions of `ls` will automatically escape any "tricky" characters by default, so the `ls` output can be copy/pasted to a new command as-is. If you have not already tried this, try simply:

```
rmdir ''$'\033'
```

Which actually is the same as:

```
rmdir $'\33'
```

Or with shells that don't support that `$'...'` form of quote from ksh93:

```
rmdir "$(printf '\33')"
```

In the `fish` shell:

```
rmdir \33
rmdir \e
```